# Was it the character's inner devil that came up in Devil?

Tags: plot-explanation, devil

I watched Devil and got the gist of the story. But am confused about the old woman (Satan?) who was in the lift. Is she really *the* Satan or just the haunting past memory of the other characters in the lift?

And also who killed who exactly? (During the flash-back of the car accident)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a simple as the Old Woman is *the* devil.

As far as who killed who:

> In a last, desperate plea for forgiveness, Tony, using a radio, confesses to a hit and run five years earlier: while drunkenly reaching for beer in his car, he smashed into another car and killed a woman (unknown to Tony that the woman was Jesse Bowden, Detective Bowden's wife) and her child.

Tony killed the Detective's wife and child.